# How do the bonus modes differ from the normal game?

Tags: cthulhu-saves-the-world

After finishing Cthulhu Saves the World, some new game modes were unlocked - `Highlander`, `Overkill`, `Cthulhu's Angels` and some sort of boss rush. Before playing through though I'm curious if there are enough differences to keep me interested for one more playthrough, or if the changes are mostly cosmetic.

How do each of the bonus modes differ from the normal game?

Comment: Hello ver. I've edited your quesiton to remove the subjective aspects. Subjective questions are considered off-topic as outlined in our [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the answer @[AshleyNunn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/38839/14629) posted didn't contain enough information (it was more or less exactly the same as what the game tells you), I looked into it a bit.

`Highlander` and `Overkill` mode, seem pretty straightforward, as Ashley mentioned - bigger XP boosts and some limitations in the former, or just ludicrous powerlevelling in the latter.

In the `Score Attack` mode it seems that though you are underleveled from not encountering random enemies, you still have to walk through empty dungeons to reach the bosses. So it isn't exactly a *boss rush* in the common meaning of the phrase.

The `Cthulhu's Angels` mode seems to be substantially different. The main storyline is heavily altered, including the dialogue and characters. (E.g. one of your enemies in the standard mode becomes your ally, etc.) There are only four characters available (all of them girls, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

here is a description of each of the bonus modes from the game summary on [GamersGate](http://www.gamersgate.com/DD-CSW/cthulhu-saves-the-world):

> Highlander mode – XP gains are quadrupled, but only one character can
> be brought into battle at a time!
>
> Score Attack mode – Gain points by defeating bosses at the lowest LV possible!
>
> Overkill – Jump to LV40 in a single battle! Perfect for replays and experimentation!
>
> Cthulhu's Angels mode – Remix mode with new playable characters, new dialogue,
> new bosses, and more!